# Flutter: Error: Method not found: 'createClient'

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors

I was running my flutter app yesterday afternoon and it was running well

but yesterday at night, I tried to run the app but the build failed with the error message being shown up

The Error Message

```
/C:/flutter-SDK/flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/client.dart:35:23: Error: Method not found: 'createClient'.
  factory Client() => createClient();
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter-SDK\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter-SDK\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 42s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


=============================================================================================
flutter doctor:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.685], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

run below command:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Comment: I run the command above but did not work!